# How to use SQL to approximately match two columns in two tables?

Tags: sql, teradata

I have two tables `A` and `B`. Table A has two columns `cust_id` and `address`, with data like

```
'12345678', '457 Edinburgh Ln Heber City UT 84032-1442'
```

Table B has only one column, `highvalue_blocks` which stores plenty of names. Names are the parts of Table A `address` column.

For example, one of `highvalue_blocks` might be `'Ln Heber City'`.

`'Ln Heber City'` is part of `'457 Edinburgh Ln Heber City UT 84032-1442'`. It should be approved.

**Question**: how to write a SQL statement to query the `address` to check whether the `high values blocks` is in it, or not?

I try to use this SQL:

```
SELECT A.CUST_ID
FROM A
WHERE A.ADDRESS LIKE (SELECT '%'||B.HIGHVALUE_BLOCKS||'%' FROM B)
```

It works. But I think it can be solve more efficiently, because it takes a long time to be finish.

Please give a hand. Thank you very much.

Comment: This join based on LIKE will result in a cross join (product join in Explain), consuming lots of resources, of course. What's the number of rows in both tables?

Comment: @dnoeth . . . Does the query actually work?  I would expect it to return an error that the subquery returns more than one row.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: It will fail as is, but I assume the missing keyword ANY was added in the real query, otherwise the OP wouldn't complain about *long time to finish* :-) LIKE can reference a list of patterns in Teradata and this list can be provided by a subquery, e.g. `col LIKE ANY ('...', '...')` for ORed and `LIKE ALL` for ANDed conditions.

Answer (score 0):

In relational database you should relate 2 or more table using "keys"(primary and foreign) in order to retrieve the data .
if not atleast must have one matching column
if any one of the above condition satisfy  then you can do inner join to retrieve the data

its a good practise to implement **

> Normalization

** when ever you construct a RDMBS tables

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While you are right, the right thing is to have a normalized database schema with FKs, we all know reality tends to be messier and as such this answer doesn't help solve the question at hand. Please take a look at the [answer guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for helpful tips on providing answers.